# How unsafe is it to use std::prev with string_iterator.begin()?

Tags: c++, iterator, undefined-behavior

i have this piece of code. This function doesn't copy adjacent duplicates chars.It keeps only one of them. To do shorter, i've decided to use std::prev with iterator.begin(). I know that it's a (very) bad practice, i come from C, but in C++ is somewhat different. The undefined behavior is almost non existent. Tell me guys. I could change my method easily. If you have a faster method, i'm interested too.

```
string suppDouble(const string& str)
{
    if (str.size() <= 1) return str;

    string token;
    for (auto it = str.cbegin(); it != str.cend(); it++)
    {
        if (*(std::prev(it)) != *it) token.push_back(*it);
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: This is plain UB. You mustn't access element before `begin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::prev` effectively does `it - 1` in your case. However, it is undefined behavior to decrement a begin iterator.

[Bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator):

> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if --container.begin() is evaluated

This means, that your very first loop iteration is already UB.

Note that there is an std algorithm that does exactly what you want: [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

> Eliminates all except the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

Comment: exact i didn't think about unique. i'm stupid haha

Answer (score 1):

Think of iterator in C++ like pointer. If you don't boundary check carefully, it can point to data that doesn't belong to you. It cause `std::out_of_range` exception

Comment: I know perfectly what it means but with this code, i've never encountered undefined behavior or exception.  That's why i asked to you guys. There is unique, obviously. Problem solved

Comment: _i've never encountered undefined behavior_. You **think** you haven't encountered it, but your code **does have** UB.

Comment: Probably, you're right for sure but i wanted tu be sure it was UB. In C, it's far more brutal when there are UB.

Comment: I think that the reason why it called `undefined behavior`. It is unpredictable